# Using Collator with Ukrainian language

Tags: java, collator

Please look at my method where I try to implement Collator to sort Objects with a "title" field.
Method:

```
public List<SchoolSubject> findAllByOrderByTitle() {
    List<SchoolSubject> schoolSubjects = subjectRepository.findAllByOrderByTitle();

    Collator uaCollator = Collator.getInstance(new Locale("ua", "UA"));
    uaCollator.setStrength(Collator.SECONDARY);
    schoolSubjects.stream().sorted((s1, s2)->uaCollator.compare(s1.getTitle(), s2.getTitle()));
    return schoolSubjects;
}
```

It sorts, but not correctly. Letter "i" is put at the very beginning.
Whats wrong with it?

Answer (score 3):

I think that you should use `new Locale("uk", "UA")`

Check this site about [Internationalization](http://www.localeplanet.com/java/uk-UA/index.html)

**EDIT:**

I think that problem is with the way Ukrainian Alphabet is represented.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ukrainian_alphabet#Unicode

According to Wikipedia, 'i' is the lastest letter considering Unicodes. So maybe you sort in descending order instead of ascending?

Comment: Thanks for correcting me with new Locale("uk", "UA")

Answer (score 3):

Correct code:

```
public List<SchoolSubject> findAllByOrderByTitle() {
    List<SchoolSubject> schoolSubjects = subjectRepository.findAllByOrderByTitle();

    Collator uaCollator = Collator.getInstance(new Locale("uk", "UA"));
    uaCollator.setStrength(Collator.PRIMARY);
    schoolSubjects.sort((s1, s2)->uaCollator.compare(s1.getTitle(), s2.getTitle()));
    return schoolSubjects;
}
```

Fixed with new Locale("uk", "UA"), excluded stream() from lambda and it sorted correctly.